# how to seperate the configuration files of Ubuntu 20.04 and KDE Plasma Desktop Environment?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, kubuntu, settings, system-settings

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04 focal** and I have **KDE plasma** (Kubuntu 21.04) installed on it.I want to know that is there any way so that `if I change settings in the KDE then it does not affect the settings in the Ubuntu .`.

[image]

Comment: Plasma is not the same as Kubuntu, and 20.04 is a completely seprate release from 21.04. It's unclear what you really have installed, and the question is much too vague about exactly which settings you are asking about. As currently written, I think this question seems unanswerable.

Comment: To have both, you're talking about a dual boot system where they automatically isolated unless you've made changes to your configuration to use the same partitions/directories in both systems (where how you've done that is your answer, which we don't know thus can't help you).  If you aren't talking about a dual-boot setup, then you're no longer running 20.04 or *focal* and I'd suggest exploring what you're actually running...

Comment: I was saying that if I have Ubuntu installed and KDE Desktop Environment on Ubuntu (for which I have taken refernce from [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-on-ubuntu/) ). So how should I seperate the settings been performed in KDE plasma Environment does not affect the Ubuntu Enviromnment.

Comment: Having multiple desktops installed isn't really an issue, but they'll be the same release.  Kubuntu uses KDE Plasma, a Qt5 environment, which differs significantly from Ubuntu which uses GNOME & GTK3, thus they'll keep most things separate  (I have GNOME installed on my system, as well as Xubuntu/XFCE & what I'm using now Lubuntu/LXQt - I think of the system though as just Ubuntu.. selecting the desktop I use at login; LXQt today) Your system however will be 20.04 or *focal* and I don't see how 21.04 applies.

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking though.... My own system with GNOME, XFCE & LXQt for example; the configuration for each is in different directories; apps are available in each... just as they are in other boxes (box to my right has Kubuntu/KDE & Lubuntu/LXQt).   Most desktops have their own configs, though it's common for GTK based ones to use the same; however that doesn't apply to GNOME & KDE Plasma.

Comment: Ok I have installed KDE Plasma on Ubuntu GNOME and now I am [unable to login](https://askubuntu.com/q/1342050/1174644)