# Unable to login !!! "Enter" key not working?

Tags: keyboard, login, plasma, sddm

Ok hi there,I have been using Ubuntu Gnome 20.04 and I have insalled the KDE plasma environment on Ubuntu from help of the reference taken from [You tube](https://youtu.be/L1JDSSWJRQY).Now after it had installed and restarts I get the sddm login screen, and the problem comes here.

[image: sddm login screen]

My keyboads all the keys are working but the **enter** key not working. But when I try `tty command line interface` for login the **enter key is working** .

Now I am unable to login ??

Comment: First, reboot. It may magically heal itself by booting.

Comment: Is this a lapop that only has one [Return] key, or a PC keyboard with a numeric block on the right with a separate [Enter] key there? (Notice that the big one next to the letter keys is [Return], not [Enter]; which mostly is the same, but not always)

Comment: Also, check the little flag at the top. It says "US", and it will probably (!) only change the language. But maybe it changes the keyboard layout as well. Check if another option there works better for you (if there are any other options).

Comment: After rebooting also it not helped. Also it is a laptop with PC keyboard attached as my laptop keyboard not working . And there is only one keyboard layout only

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: Did you try a different keyboard? Maybe it's really the keyboard's fault.

Comment: Not a solution but a possible workaround... The ENTER key is usually sending a Carriage Return (CR) character to the system when it is pressed. Pressing CTRL-M instead of the ENTER key may allow you to get past that and then figure out what's wrong with the keyboard mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to resolve this issue:

- Enter into Recovery Mode[Linux variant OS - e.g. Ubuntu]
- Choose shell command prompt
- login using your personal account
- run command "startx"
- GUI will appear and then turn on Wifi
- Run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade"
- Restart the OS

Above steps helped to resolve my keyboard issue.